# Highcharts - Return string to other container on hover

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I need to display multiple series data to other div on hover and display its series total value when not hovered. Here is a good example but still need to display series total as mentioned http://jsfiddle.net/RfnUk/.

```
<div id="left" style="float:left; width: 200px; min-height: 10px;"></div>
<div id="container" style="height: 400px; float: left;"></div>
```

Now, I want to show this data to the div with ***left*** id

```
tooltip: {
    crosshairs: true,
    formatter: function() {
        var s = '<b>'+ this.x +'</b>';

        $.each(this.points, function(i, point) {
            s += '<br/>'+ point.series.name +': '+
                point.y +'m';
        });
        $("#left").html(s);
        return false;
    },
    shared: true
},
```

Here is its working sample

```js
$(function() {
  $('#container').highcharts({

    chart: {},

    xAxis: {
      categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul',
        'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'
      ]
    },

    tooltip: {
      crosshairs: true,
      formatter: function() {
        var s = '<b>' + this.x + '</b>';

        $.each(this.points, function(i, point) {
          s += '<br/>' + point.series.name + ': ' +
            point.y + 'm';
        });
        $("#left").html(s);
        return false;
      },
      shared: true
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
      },
      {
        data: [216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5]
      }
    ]

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="left" style="float:left; width: 200px; min-height: 10px;"></div>
<div id="container" style="height: 400px; float: left;"></div>
```

Comment: total value of last hovered series or the total series  value. clarify

Comment: I mean total series value. like series 1: total  and  series 2: total ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can loop through the data of your series after the chart is rendered and calculate

```
var series = $("#container").highcharts().series;
for (var i in series){
    var total = 0;
    for (var j in series[i].data){
    total += series[i].data[j].y
  }
  $("#left-total").append("<label>" + series[i].name + "=" + total + "</label><br/>");
}
```

here is the full fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/RfnUk/9/

Your totals for the 2 series was the same so i edited the last point of the second series you don't think it's an error

To show the left part only when you hover you hide it by default, show it on the tooltip event and hide it on the mouseOut event like so

```
    plotOptions: {
        line: {
            point: {
                events: {
                    mouseOut: function () {
                        $("#left-total").hide();
                        $("#left").hide();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

full fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/RfnUk/10/

Comment: But how to display it only when I'm not hovering the chart.

Comment: Thank you @Liviu Boboia, you saved my day.